# Github pages shows 404 File not found

Tags: github-pages

I'm new to gh-pages. 
Here is the link to my repro https://github.com/VishalChothani/vishalchothani.github.io

I changed my repro name from `project` to `vishalchothani.github.io`

before when I use to do `https://vishalchothani.github.io/project` it worked fine, but now 
`https://vishalchothani.github.io` is giving me 404. 
I'm not sure what I did wrong, Can somebody please help me to figure out the problem. 
Thanks

Error: 404 Page not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at github.io [documentation](https://pages.github.com/), and it seams like you need to push your builded code on master branch.

```
git add --all

git commit -m "Initial commit"

git push -u origin master
```

On your repository, `index.html` is on `gh-pages` branch.

You can browse existing working repo to compare with yours : https://github.com/search?q=github.io